# File Upload in asp.net C#- Null reference error

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am trying to use file upload control to upload and then download file using Asp.net C#, But it is giving me a Null reference exception(Object reference not set to an instance of an object). Can anybody help me with this, where I am making the mistake?

Here is my aspx code:

```
<div>
      <table style="padding: 20px;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFilename" runat="server" Text="Browse:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload1" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="OnLnkUpload" runat="server" OnClick="OnLnkUpload_Click" Font-Underline="False">Upload</asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="OnLnkDownload" runat="server" OnClick="OnLnkDownload_Click" Font-Underline="False">Download</asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Here is my code behind file:

```
string filename = string.Empty;

    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void OnLnkUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        filename = Path.GetFileName(fileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        fileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Files/" + filename));

        Response.Write("File uploaded sucessfully.");
        lblFilename.Text = "Files/" + fileUpload1.FileName;
    }

    // To download uplaoded file
    protected void OnLnkDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lblFilename.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            if (lblFilename.Text.EndsWith(".txt"))
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/txt";
            }
            else if (lblFilename.Text.EndsWith(".pdf"))
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            }
            else if (lblFilename.Text.EndsWith(".docx"))
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/docx";
            }
            else
            {
                Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
            }

            string filePath = lblFilename.Text;

            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filePath + "\"");
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(filePath));
            Response.End();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line is giving the error?

Comment: you need to change the code in your OnLnk_UpLoad event I will post an example of what I have just written and tested real quick

Comment: Gridly-  fileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Files/" + filename)); This is giving an error that object reference not set to an instance of an object. what should I change in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following in my case I have added a Button and after selecting what file I want to upload I have this method in my button click event

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        this.FileUpload1.SaveAs(targetFolder + this.FileUpload1.FileName);
        lblResult.Visible = true;
        lblResult.Text = string.Format("{0} Successfully Uploaded", this.FileUpload1.FileName);
    }
}
```

aspx code

```
<div class="qsf-fb-group qsf-fb-attachments">
    <strong>Stappings UpLoad</strong>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" ToolTip="Browse for files on local Machine" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="UpLoad Selected File" onclick="Button1_Click" ToolTip="Click to Upload File to Server" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the condition upload control contain file or not. like below...

```
if (this.FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    //Block of Code
}
```